# is adding methods to a element classed as extending DOM elements

Tags: javascript

I have heard that extending DOM Elements is bad...

Is this classed as extending a DOM Element, if so is this so bad?

It works in IE7+ (tested). So why not?

```
var app = {};

app.get = function( selector ){
  return this.wrap( document.getElementById( selector ) );
};

app.wrap = function( element ) {
    for( var func in this ) {
        element[func] = this[ func ];
    }
    return element;
};

app.text = function( text ) {
     alert( text );   
}

app.get('test').text('Welcome');
```

**Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/gzb6C/2/**

Comment: It's bad practice, but yes it works. My advice is to create your own namespace like `element.my[func] = this[func]`

Comment: Ok, it's bad practice, but why? `element.my.text('Welcome');` kind of defeats the object of ..... everything

Comment: NO, this is not an answer or tip but is a doubt of my own, what is `this` means in the above code, I know what it means in Java, but what does it mean here, I mean it can't be related to scope, can it?

Comment: `this === app`, and it's a comment i know!

Comment: then it is same as in Java, the current obj!

Comment: @rps ok, soooo........

Comment: Nothing... Just clearing my own doubt! you go ahead with your sleek coding.

Comment: Apparently, it's supposed to perform bad, since you're doing an awefull lot of copying of functions (that you normally wouldn't need). jQuery's practice of creating a wrapper is considered better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's usually considered "bad" because it can cause conflicts. As an example, at one point in time, Ext JS & prototype JS both added a defer method to the function prototype, so you could call:

`foo.defer();`

The problem was, each library had different arguments to defer, so when you included both libraries it caused a whole lot of things to break, since both libraries would call `defer()` with the arguments that library was expecting.

The same *may* happen to you, as long as you take care about which libraries you import. If it's for a small personal project it's probably fine.